Combine Basic Auth and Bearer token in nginx reverse proxy
Nginx reverse proxy configuration
upstream frontend {
    server frontend:4200;
}

upstream backend {
    server backend:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}

I have a nginx which works as a reverse proxy for my app. I use Bearer token for user authentication between frontend and backend. When I set auth_basic in nginx - it's conflicts with my Bearer app auth as nginx could not have 2 Authentication headers. Are there any solutions on how to restrict access to my env and in the meantime continue to use Bearer token in APP?
PS: backend is written in NodeJS (NestJS)

This question is similar to: Conflicting Basic & Bearer Authorization between nginx and my webapp. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@IvanShatsky it's different because in question you mentioned used php server, and I can't understand how can I apply it to my example. Thanks

You can implement a similar solution by creating an API endpoint like /api/validate_token and using it within the internal authentication location defined by the auth_request directive via proxy_pass .... However, when you programmatically add an Authorization: Bearer ... header to your API call, the browser won’t include an Authorization: Basic ... header, ensuring that nginx receives only one Authorization: ... header. And if all your API endpoints are protected with Bearer authentication while your frontend is secured with Basic authentication, why bother going further?
